# missing dll file of opencv when debugging the visual studio ultimate 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

Can anybody help me. 
I already success on build the program. However, I have a problem when debug the program.

> The program can't start because opencv_calib3d.dll is missing from
>   your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem The
>   program can't start because opencv_highgui.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. The
>   program can't start because opencv_core2411d.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I'm currently doing my final year project. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

after all you have done, like include directories and adding sources you have to set "Use Library Dependency Inputs" to "yes":
Linker -> General - Set 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' to 'Yes'
good luck!